# Difference with open-uri with block and without it

Tags: ruby, open-uri

What is the difference between doing:

```
file = open('myurl')
# Do stuff with file
```

And doing:

```
open('myurl') do |file|
 # Do things with file
end
```

Do I need to close and remove the file when I am not using the block approach? If so, how do I close and remove it? I don't see any close/remove method in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)

Comment: Yes, you need to close the file if you don't use the block. Normally it's best practice to open a file do what you need to do and close it right away when possible. This is an easy way to do it.

Comment: I have edited my question, because I am not sure how to close and remove that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for OpenURI is a little opaque to beginners, but the docs for `#open` [can be found here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open).

Those docs say:

> `#open` returns an IO-like object if block is not given. Otherwise it yields the IO object and return the value of the block.

The key words here are "[IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html)-like object." We can infer from that that the object (in your examples, `file`), will respond to the `#close` method.

While the documentation doesn't say so, by looking at the source we can see that `#open` will return either a [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) or a [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) object, depending on the size of the data returned. OpenURI's [internal Buffer class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/open-uri.rb#L375-L394) first initializes a StringIO object, but if the size of the output exceeds 10,240 bytes it creates a Tempfile and writes the data to it (to avoid storing large amounts of data in memory). Both StringIO and Tempfile have behavior consistent with IO, so it's good practice (when not passing a block to `#open`), to call `#close` on the object in an `ensure`:

```
begin
  file = open(url)
  # ...do some work...
ensure
  file.close
end
```

Code in the `ensure` section always runs, even if code between `begin` and `ensure` raises an exception, so this will, well, ensure that `file.close` gets called even if an error occurs.